# Rename multiple files using part of existing filename studio

Tags: r, regex, macos, batch-rename

I have lots of files e.g.

```
MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000049_aid0001.tif
MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000113_aid0001.tif
MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000129_aid0001.tif
MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000161_aid0001.tif
```

Each of these files are named in the same pattern apart from doyYYYYDOY (year and day of year).
I would like to rename all of these files at once so that they begin DOY_YYYY_[old file name] e.g.
049_2000_MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000049_aid0001.tif

I would use Total Commander but am on a MacOS system and would prefer to have the whole solution in RStudio.

So far I can list the relevant files in the folder using:

```
temp <- list.files(pattern="^MOD")
```

I assume that this can be done with regex/gsub/sapply, but I am still new to R so please help!

Answer (score 1):

```
# list files in working directory that begin with "MOD"

    f <- as_tibble(list.files(pattern="^MOD"), header=FALSE)

# rename column as files.old

    colnames(f) <- 'files.old'

    f2 <-
      f %>%  
      # separate day of year and year into new column doy
      mutate(doy = str_after_first(files.old, "doy")) %>%
      mutate(doy = gsub('_.*','',doy)) %>%
      # extract year into new col and remove from doy col
      mutate(year = substr(doy, 1,4)) %>%
      mutate(doy = substr(doy,5,7)) %>%
      # create new file names
      mutate(files.new = paste0(doy,"_",year,"_",files.old))

# rename files

    file.rename(as.vector(f2$files.old), as.vector(f2$files.new))
```

Comment: You don't need to make multiple `mutate()` calls.

Comment: @Phil is correct - if you list multiple operations in a mutate call they are done sequentially, so you can refer to (and indeed overwrite) previous mutations within the same call. This makes for smaller code which is just as easy (IMO) to follow.